# Is there a way to force Windows to reset the keyboard connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

When I keep my computer on for a while, sometimes the keyboard stops working.

It says it's connected by USB (or bluetooth, if I change the connection type) but just doesn't actually type or receive any input.

I can resolve it by restarting the computer, but it's kind of annoying to have to do this.

I used to have a similar problem on my Ubuntu computer with the networking system. When it stopped working, I ran some command in terminal to reset the networking system, and it worked.

I'm wondering if there's something like this for Windows, and with the keyboard.

I'm on Windows 10 Home Insider Preview 21301.1010, but I should note I had the same issue before I started using the Preview build.

Comment: Can you try a different keyboard? My Windows 10 Desktop Computer with USB Keyboard and Mouse (Logi Tech) has been running 24x7 for 4 years without losing the keyboard.

Comment: Check in the Event Viewer. Do you see any logging of the issue at hand—errors showing what is failing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have another working keyboard, and the one I'm using is a nice clicky mechanical with a custom keyset I bought ... I'd really prefer to keep using this one. Really, I'm just wondering if there's a way to reset the drivers. Windows drivers can be finnicky. My USB Multihub worked at first, then didn't work for weeks, then suddently started working again.

Comment: @JG7 I'll have to try that next time it happens. Where in the logger would I see messages?

Comment: @maxpleaner you don’t have to wait for it to happen again. Error logging is kept from previous incidents. The default view should show a summary of clickable warning and error counts. Try pulling it up and see if anything stands out.

Comment: @JG7 I don't have any problem reports from today (and it happened about an hour ago), so it must not show up there

Comment: @maxpleaner Hmmmm...Windows is likely using a built in default driver. It may be a tad of a stretch, but perhaps the manufacturer of the keyboard has proprietary drivers available on their website? What is the make and model of the keyboard?

Comment: @JG7 Unfortunately not, it's [this one](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07MBZ95VV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which is Magic Refiner MK11

Comment: Does unplugging and replugging correct the issue? If so, then perhaps this is due to a Windows power saving setting.  Use this webpage and disable the setting: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/power-management-option-isnt-selected#more-information. I have experienced similar issues with other types of usb devices.

Comment: @JG7 No, nothing other than restarting seems to work. But I will try that. Yeah I wouldn't be surprised if power saving was the issue

Comment: Yeah this `USB Selective Suspend` thing seems suspicious. I disabled it. Crossing my fingers this doesn't happen again. Thanks

Comment: @maxpleaner yeah, it tends to cause more trouble than anything else. Be sure to disable it on all USB hubs on your device (some computer may have 2 or 3 in all).

Comment: This didn't work btw @JG7